# How can I obtain x(n) given y(n) and h(n) of a system using Z-Transform?

Tags: convolution, z-transform

I'm given with an output sequence $y(n)$ and impulse response of the system $h(n)$. I have to obtain the input sequence $x(n)$.

My idea is $$y(n) = x(n)\ast h(n)$$

Taking z-transform on both sides and then it becomes $$Y(z)=X(z)H(z)$$

Here after I don't know how to get $X(z)$. I'm not sure whether I could do simple division with $Y(z)$ and $H(z)$

The given sequences are

$$y(n)=\{8,22,11,31,4,12\}$$

$$h(n)=\{2,5,0,4\}$$

Please give me an idea to proceed further. Thankyou :)

Comment: You should divide and get $$X(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{H(z)}=\frac{8+22z^{-1}+11z^{-2}+31z^{-3}+4z^{-4}+12z^{-5}}{2+5z^{-1}+4z^{-3}}$$Now, do you know how to calculate the inverse transform?

Comment: Yes I know Thanks a lot